# WPF Window.GetWindow(this) odd behaviour?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have a `UserControl` in a `Window`. During the lifespan of the application, that `Window`
is sometimes closed and when the user needs it again a new instance is made.

At some point the `UserControl` needs to display a dialog and needs to pass it's parent control to that dialog as the owner. Here's the catch: the first time the `Window` is created
and the control has to show a dialog, everything works just fine. It calls `Window.GetWindow(this)` and passes the result to the dialog. However, when the `Window` is closed and later a new instance is created and the `UserControl` opens the dialog, then I get the following exception:

> Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has been closed.

Whenever the `Window` is created, this code is called:

```
var window = new ControllerConfigurationWindow() { Owner = this };
```

So it's clearly a new instance, and of course while displaying the dialog, the window is open... I'm not closing it anywhere...

So I'm wondering - and it makes no sense in my mind as I say this - but could it be that `Window.GetWindow(this)` somehow gives me the parent of an old instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind... I wasn't thinking...
This is what happened:

When the Window is created, the event handlers are hooked up,
  but I didn't unhook them anywhere... so the code was indeed 
  called on a window that was already closed.